# Webpack: двухсторонний обмен данными между модулями

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

Пусть `main.js` - главный файл webpack-сборки, `module1.js` - модуль, подключаемый к main.js. Если нам нужны переменные из `module1.js` в `main.js`, то это сделать [легко](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-modules), но что если наоборот нам нужны переменные в `module1.js` из `main.js`? Возможен ли двухсторонний обмен данными между модулями?

Answer (score -2):

Вообще, если `main.js` - точка входа то `require` от неё делать нельзя. Но с использованием `export` и `import` у меня получилось сделать двухсторонний обмен данными между точкой входа и модулем (для сборки использовал `webpack 2`).